# Meterpreter over SSH

Tags: ssh, metasploit

I was reading a few tutorials about using `plink.exe`to create an ssh tunnelled meterpreter session. However this reverse connection seems to just bring me right back to my own host computer, unlike the common windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp, which connects back to me but allows me to access my windows computer(target). How does the tunnel back to my own computer with plink encrypt the current Meterpreter session with ssh? The tutorials said to background the shell that I ran plink.exe in. Unfortunately, I read that there is a bug in Metetepreter where you can't Ctl-Z windows shells. Am I actually suppose to background the session?

Answer (score 1):

- *Tunnel:*
  A tunnel through a background meterpreter session could be used for [Pivoting](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/pivoting/). 
  **Pivoting** allows you to gain access to an internal network firewall-protected, through an already compromised target(client-side-attack). SSH/plink.exe is also a way to create that tunnel.
- *Background session:* 
  You can run an exploit directly in background with `exploit -j`.
  `msf exploit(ms10_002_aurora) > exploit -j
  [*] Exploit running as background job.`